# File upload in grid renames file field

Tags: ee2, file-uploads, grid

EE 2.10.1
Uploading a pdf with file field in Grid renames the file field but not the file when using non-standard characters, resulting in this error when trying to edit the entry:

> An Error Was Encountered
>   File /www/…/test%2B.jpg does not exist.

ex. uploading test+.pdf gets renamed to test%2B.pdf in grid but is still called test+.pdf on the server

Am i missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a fix for the filenames with special characters issue in EE2.10.3. Doing an upgrade should fix it.

Comment: This fixed it but broke structure instead, fix for structure was found here:  https://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/22891-fatal-error-on-ee2111